# Download Locally MS Server Database in Android APP

Tags: android, sql-server, sqlite

I need to develop an Android App (with Android Studio), and Manage a MS Server Database (locally).
Then I need to download these tables in the APP.
This DB is approximately 200MB.
And the database is in MS Server 2008.

The best way is create the same database in Sql lite, and synchronise these two databases? Otherwise exist the simplest solution?

Thanks a lot
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you two different solutions:

1. You could connect to MS Server, make all the necessary queries to download all data from that DB and, finally, update your local SQLite DB.
2. You could export your MS Server DB (make a dump) and import it to your local SQLite DB.

I think the first solution is more efficient but the second solution is easier.

Comment: woow thank you Mariusz, you have a great idea. I prefer the first solution :)